# Javascript object to function namespacing

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, javascript-namespaces

I have an object like this

```
var a={
    b:{
        sayHi:function(){
            alert("hi");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to convert it into function name spacing using prototypes. How can I convert ? I tried following. but not working

```
var a=function(){};

a.prototype.b=function(){};

b.prototype.sayHi=function(){
        alert("hi");
}

var obj=new a();
obj.b.sayHi();
```

Any Help ?

Comment: Note: "ReferenceError: b is not defined"

Comment: Defining "not working" is usually critical to getting the kind of help you're after. Your error message, as Matt Ball pointed out, really lets you know some useful information.

Comment: That's not how "namespaces" or prototypes work.

Comment: And that. You know, I regret answering. Retracting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
var A = function(){},
    B = function(){};
A.prototype.b = new B();
B.prototype.sayHi = function(){
        alert("hi");
}

var obj=new A();
obj.b.sayHi();
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Oriol. Which method you would prefer ? like object or prototype ?